# User ID's in User Information List are updated/changed

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, user-profile, user-profile-service, ad, user-information-list

In which scenario's user id's will update/changed?

Any help much appreciated.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: The user ID is set to all users who currently have access to the site collection. Old user account that are deleted are removed from SharePoint (through the user profile sync) and the hidden user lists where the account had permissions. I belive that if an active users permission are removed from a site, they will still remain in the hidden list.

Comment: The User ID's in User Information List are updated/changed.                      For example, User ID =100 earlier, But when I verified recently it is 101.           I Observed this behavior for 200 users out of 400 users in User Information List. No clue why the user id's have been updated.